# I am getting this issue, I tried using kotlin coroutines and Async still getting the same Calling this from Your main thread can lead to deadlock,

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I also made another class that implements runnable to make a new thread still it's now working,
Also tried with Aynctask. At last, I made a view model but still same issue.
Anyone, please Help.
Here is what I am trying to do

```
GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO){

                uploadFileToGDrive("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Ticket.pdf",this@AddPost)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    Toast.makeText(this@AddPost,"I have gone Mad",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                
            }

        }



fun createFile (filePath:String):String{
        var file:File=File(filePath)
        val gfile = com.google.api.services.drive.model.File()
        gfile.setName(file.name)
        var mediaContent:FileContent= FileContent("application/pdf",file)
        try {
            var myFile= mDrive?.files()?.create(gfile,mediaContent)?.execute()
            var listOfPermission: MutableList<com.google.api.services.drive.model.Permission>? =myFile!!.permissions
            if(listOfPermission!=null){
                for (per in listOfPermission){
//                    Toast.makeText(this,per.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
//            Toast.makeText(this,"Uploaded Files",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return  myFile!!.id
        }
        catch (e:Exception){
//            Toast.makeText(this,"Some Error Occured in Uploading Files"+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return "Failed"
    }
```

I am running this function on a button click in an activity tried all the methods from coroutines to Aync and making new thread still getting the same issue.
[image: You can see the Exception]

Comment: `At last, I made a view model but still same issue` viewmodels don't change threading, so i'm not sure why you would believe it would make a difference here. nothing you've shown here indicates that this work wouldn't be done on the main thread ?

Comment: Can you show your code where you attempted to use coroutines or a runnable? We can tell you what was wrong with it. Otherwise, all we can do is quote generalized tutorials, which probably won't help since you're still stuck after presumably looking at tutorials.

Comment: This is how I am calling the function
GlobalScope.launch {
            Log.d("AddPost",Thread.currentThread().name)
            uploadFileToGDrive("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Ticket.pdf",this@AddPost)

        }

Comment: That code you shared calls `uploadFileToGDrive`, but you're showing a function named `createFile`. Hard to tell what could be going wrong without seeing your actual code that causes the problem. Coroutines are not a trivial subject to learn that you can use successfully by trial and error. You need to read the documentation carefully and grasp all the basic concepts first.

Comment: Both the functions are same just the name is different.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception? If `createFile` is being called from `Dispatchers.IO`, it would not cause that exception because it would not be run on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use GlobalScope, instead use lifeCycleScope.
This might resolve the issue.